# Get specific data from Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

In my application, i get the data on traffic and conversions from my account using Google Analytics Core Reporting API and Multi-Channel-Funnels Reporting API.

For to get a traffic data, I use the GET command from Core Reporting API.

In this command I give, among other things, necessary to display parameters (dimensions and metrics), and filtering options data for my request - filter and segment (I use dynamic segments). 
Here's an example of one of the queries:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?
ids=ga:XXXXXXXXXX &
start-date=2013-03-05 &
end-date=2013-04-04 &
metrics=ga:visits,ga:pageviewsPerVisit,ga:avgTimeOnSite,ga:percentNewVisits,ga:entranceBounceRate &
dimensions=ga:source,ga:keyword &
filters=ga:visits>0 &
segment=dynamic::ga:medium==CPA,ga:medium==CPC,ga:medium==cpm;ga:campaign!@img_ &
sort=-ga:visits &
key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This query returns me the results of the traffic data match the condition of filter and segment.

But when i wanted to return the data conversion for the same data with the MCF Reporting API, i encountered a problem. 
GET command from MCF Reporting API does not contain the "Segment", and the filter does not allow write OR conditions.

Although the web interface Google Analytics has the ability to apply segments for data conversion. I've read. that we can apply Channel Groupings to the query results in the web interface, but they are tied to the account. And because I'm using a service account for authentication and working with API, to me they are not available. I do not know how to apply them in the API.

How do I filter the melon for the conversion in the request that they udoletvoryali Writing the above condition?

Is there a way to solve my problem? 
Thanks, sorry for my English.

Comment: I'm able to OR filter in GA multi-channel using comma-separated values, as with regular GA.  Have you tried this?  I can't speak to segments.